# Create a pop-up list to fill a textView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm new to android studio and the layouts, I'm trying to recreate something that I don't even know how it's called, which makes difficult to find answers. I have re-create in the image below the thing I'm trying to accomplish :

[My layout idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RIaK.png)

What I would like to do is 1 : To have a textView asking to choose something. 2 : When we click on it a popup appear displaying different things to choose, we could scroll through those things if the list is long. 3 : Then when clicking on the thing we want our choice is displayed in the textView.

After some research the closest thing that I've found are "drop-down menu", but it does not really match what I'm aiming for (displayed below text instead of popup, no way to scroll inside if the list of things is long, at least for the tutorial I've found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AlertDialog` and `setItems` to pass array string.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
        .setItems(R.array.colors_array,
                  DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                            // of the selected item
         })
builder.create()
```

Where `R.array.colors_array` is your array, you can define it in XML or programmatically.

Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#AddingAList)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot ! That seems to be what I was searching for ! I try it later this evening and tell you if I manage to do it :)
If you have a long array the list will be scrollable ?

Comment: @Tritize yes it will scroll, nice to help you :)